# AWS Cognito not working in react native (android)

Tags: android, react-native, aws-amplify, amazon-cognito-identity-js

i am using AWS Amplify for authentication in react native app Auth.signIn() method does not give any response its does not give success or error response. **In IOS its working fine.** **In Android its  working in simulator but not working in real device in release mode.**

```
await Auth.signIn(bioEmail?bioEmail:email,bioPass?bioPass:password)
  .then(async (user) => {})
```

used versions

```
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-native": "^0.63.4"
"amazon-cognito-identity-js": "^4.3.0", 
"aws-amplify": "3.0.22", 
"aws-amplify-react-native": "4.2.3", 
"@react-native-community/netinfo": "6.2.1"
```

It worked previously but from yesterday its only working in ios, android login is not working.

Comment: same issue here please help

Comment: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/5539

Comment: above link is not working